# Strange sorting behavior with bigint column via GiST index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm, btree-gist

I'm working on implementing a fast text search in PostgreSQL 12.6 (Ubuntu 20.04.2 VBox) with custom sorting, and I'm using **pg_trgm** along with GiST (**btree_gist**) index for sorted output. The idea is to return top 5 matching artists that have the highest number of plays. The index is created like this:

```sql
create index artist_name_gist_idx on artist 
  using gist ("name" gist_trgm_ops, total_play_count) where active = true;
```

"name" here is of type `varchar(255)` and total_play_count is `bigint`, no nulls allowed.

When I query the table like this:

```
select id, name, total_play_count 
from artist 
where name ilike '%the do%' and active = true 
order by total_play_count <-> 40312 
limit 5;
```

I get the correct result:

```
   id   |          name           | total_play_count 
--------+-------------------------+------------------
   1757 | The Doors               |             1863
 733226 | Damsel in the Dollhouse |             1095
   9758 | The Doobie Brothers     |             1036
 822805 | The Doubleclicks        |              580
   7236 | Slaughter and the Dogs  |              258
```

I would get the same result if I replace `total_play_count <-> 40312` with simple `total_play_count desc`, but then I get the additional sort operation that I want to avoid. Number **40312** here is the current maximum value of this column, and table itself contains 1612297 rows in total.

However, since total_play_count is of type bigint, I wanted to make this query more general (and faster) and use the maximum value for bigint, so I don't have to query for the max value every time. But when I update the ORDER BY clause with `total_play_count <-> 9223372036854775807`, I get the following result:

```
   id    |          name           | total_play_count 
---------+-------------------------+------------------
    1757 | The Doors               |             1863
  822805 | The Doubleclicks        |              580
    9758 | The Doobie Brothers     |             1036
  733226 | Damsel in the Dollhouse |             1095
 1380763 | Bruce Bawss The Don     |               10
```

The ordering here is broken, and it's even worse when I try the same approach on another table that has a lot more rows. There are no negative or overly large values, so overflow shouldn't be possible. Results of `explain` are almost identical:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.41..6.13 rows=5 width=34)
   ->  Index Scan using artist_name_gist_idx on artist  (cost=0.41..184.44 rows=161 width=34)
         Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~* '%the do%'::text)
         Order By: (total_play_count <-> '9223372036854775807'::bigint)
```

What could be the issue here? Is this a bug with `btree_gist`, or am I missing something? I could settle for querying for the max value, but it worries me that there is a threshold that might be reached eventually and break the search, which would be a shame since I'm quite happy with the performance.

---

**Update:**

I've tried using regular integer type instead of bigint, and then query with it's upper bound `total_play_count <-> 2147483647`. It seems that there is no such problem with it. Perhaps using `bigint` in the first place was somewhat optimistic, but I'll keep the question open in case anyone has an answer or a workaround.